# Pycharm not finding module installed (dnspython) in venv

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm hoping the community can help me with a project I'm working on.

I'm trying to retrieve txt records in a python script, and am attempting to use dnspython.  I installed the module in they PyCharm venv, and have confirmed that the python interpreter configured for the project is the venv python interpreter.  When I try to import DNS.resolver at the top of my script, it autocompletes, and finds the package (screenshot below).  When I try to run the script,  I get an error "No module named 'dns'"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2022.1\scratches\scratch.py", line 1, in <module>
    import DNS.resolver
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Security_Assessment\venv\lib\site-packages\DNS\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from dns.version import version as __version__  # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dns'
```

[Screenshot of Pycharm finding module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkNcS.png)

If anyone can help me fix this one and allow me to get on with my project, I would appreciate it tremendously!!
Thanks!

Comment: Check [the docs](https://dnspython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/name-make.html) the base package should be written using lower case. If you write `import dns.resolver` instead of `import DNS.resolver` it should work.

Comment: Thanks,  I did that, to no avail.  Oddly enough, import DNS.resolver finds the module while dns.resolver does not (Windows).

I did fix my problem through brute force: I deleted the project folder and started over, and now everything works as advertised.